# Call recorder for Samsung J7 Max

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

Whats the best recommendation for a voice call recorder for an unrooted Samsung J7 Max. I am not talking about Whatsapp calls, I am referring to calls over SIM and over VoLTE.

I am already using [Calls Recall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eupheme.callrecorder&hl=en), but it's really buggy and I am looking for a stable alternative.

I am looking for suggestions for paid and unpaid apps.

Answer (score 2):

i can't guarantee that it works with your phone but i guess your best chances would be with [**Call Recorder**](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.axet.callrecorder/) from [axet](https://gitlab.com/axet).

it has several cool features:

- you can **choose the source for recording** (Auto, System Default, System RAW, Voice Line or Mic), since the audio-streams are handled different from phone to phone. - if it seems to not work, simply try & error...
- it is **free** and open source (GPLv3)
- you can choose between some well known formats like opus, ogg, flac, etc.
- has an optional auto-delete feature after a given time
- additional you can set mono/stereo, the sample rate, the name and storage path,...

Comment: Good choice (+1), I'd second that – especially as it is FOSS and available via F-Droid (very good points concerning privacy). If you're looking for alternatives, ng.newbie, be welcome to check with my corresponding app listing: [Call Recorder](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_98).